# Can I send parameter to the Interface in kotlin?

Tags: android, api, kotlin, interface, retrofit

I use interface for @Get in retrofit API request, instead of creating @Get functions for each call I want to send a parameter to the @Get function, How can I do that? Like below example

interface SomeApiService(catId: String) {

```
@GET(EN_PRODUCTLIST+catId)
fun getProductByCatId():
        Deferred<SomeProduct>
```

}

object SomeApi {
val retrofitService : SomeApiService by lazy { retrofit.create(SomeApiService::class.java) }
}

than when I call SomeApi(catId).getProductByCatId(), it will return that specific product by catId.
how to do that?

Comment: no thats not how interfaces work

Comment: than how can I send a request to @Get(productAtId) from outside? Do you know how can I do that?

Comment: why are you not sending it in your function?

Comment: will it effect in @Get ?

Comment: do you mean like: @GET(EN_PRODUCTLIST)
fun getProductByCatId(catId: String):
        Deferred<SomeProduct>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you would have to do this

```
@GET("EN_PRODUCTLIST{catId}")
fun getProductByCatId(@Path(catId) catId:String):Deferred<SomeProduct>
```

the @Path puts the parameter into the url path of the request.

Please read through the documentation again https://square.github.io/retrofit/